# How to move a project from the projects root to projects root/trunk?

Tags: svn, branch, move

I am confronted with a rather strange svn repository structure where every project is in a subdirectory of the repositories trunk like so:

```
/branches
/tags
/trunk/projects/cool_app/src
/trunk/projects/hot_app/src
```

Now we are moving to a tag/branch/trunk structure inside the individual projects like so

```
/branches
/tags
/trunk/projects/cool_app/tags/
/trunk/projects/cool_app/branches/
/trunk/projects/cool_app/trunk/src
```

New apps have their internal trunks. However, the old apps have their src directly in their project's directory.

```
/trunk/projects/hot_app/src
```

How can I move the src  from project_name/src to project_name/trunk/src,such that I get

```
/trunk/projects/cool_app/trunk/src
```

without running into the problems regarding older working copies described in this question:
 [Is there a clean way to move / to /trunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753789/subversion-oops-any-way-to-move-to-trunk)

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an svn mv command would do the trick - svn is smart enough to remember move/copy/delete history in this kind of case.