# How to move files from repo root to trunk sub-directory when using assembla

Tags: svn

I've created a private project and one repository at assembla.
But I've made the mistake of not following the convention with the subdirectories.
So, now there are source files in the repo root directory.
How can I move them into /trunk subdir?

Reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753789/is-there-a-clean-way-to-move-to-trunk), I saw that I have to have shell access to run the svnadmin commands.
I've tried bypassing them, and succeeded only in getting a dump of the repo and creating a new one.
I am stuck at the step in which I need to load the dump into the /trunk directory - I can only load it into root again.

I see that `svn move` isn't a good option since there might be a case of wanting to return  to an older revision, but since I am in the really early steps of the development of the project, it is unlikely for me to want to do that.
So should I try `svn move`? If so, how should I do that? `svn move ./ ./trunk/` would do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got three options.

1. Use `svn copy ^/ ^/trunk` from your working copy (^/ is shorthand
   for the root of the repository) and then use `svn delete` on each
   file in your root.  This will preserve properties you placed on the
   repository root such as svn:ignore.  You can then use `svn switch`
   to move your checkouts to the trunk directory.  If you want to
   checkout the history from before you do this you'll have to checkout
   the root of the repository at the old revisions, which may be
   inconvenient (this is your comment about why you might not want to
   use move).  This method might fail depending on the version of httpd
   on the server side (due to a bug in Apache httpd that has been fixed).  This method is documented in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019001/svn-create-top-level-directory-and-move-everything-from-root?rq=1
2. Create a new trunk directory and then use `svn move` on each
   file/directory in your root of your repository.  This won't preserve
   any properties from the root directory, but saves you an extra
   command.  You can then use `svn switch` to move your checkouts to
   the trunk directory, but since the new directory won't be related to the new directory you'll have to use `--ignore-ancesstry` when calling switch.  If you want to checkout the history from
   before you do this you'll have to checkout the root of the
   repository at the old revisions, which may be inconvenient (this is
   your comment about why you might not want to use move).  This method is documented in this existing question: [How to create trunk directory in existing svn repo without a trunk, and move all files to new trunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067217/how-to-create-trunk-directory-in-existing-svn-repo-without-a-trunk-and-move-all?rq=1)
3. Dump your repository.  When you load the repository with svnadmin load
   make sure to use `--ignore-uuid` and `--parent-dir trunk`.  Existing checkouts will no longer
   be usable and you'll have to create new checkouts.  You'll be able
   to move around in history with just a simple `svn update -r $REV`
   since all of the history will be in your trunk (well except for any
   branches you might make).  This is documented in this question: [Is there a clean way to move / to /trunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753789/is-there-a-clean-way-to-move-to-trunk)

Which you use is really up to you.  As you can see there are some tradeoffs.  The first two aren't really that different.  The third one is more of a pain.  I'd imagine it depends on if there are other developers that will be inconvenienced by breaking their checkouts.  If it's just you then I'd go ahead with the 3rd option.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, Ben. The problem is that as I am using assembla I cannot use svnadmin as I don't have shell access to the server. Also, as I still don't have any svn:ignore properties in my root I just might go with the second choice. Two questions, `svn switch` simply declares the argument as the new working copy? Cause I've done these: `svn move file1 file2 dir1 dir2 trunk/` and it moved all the files from repo root and dir1 dir2 files to trunk. The two directories were left at the repo root. So I then used svn move for files of dir1 to dir1, etc. Now everything seems fine.

Comment: I then tried an `svn switch` and it failed with an error about ancenstry. So I had to run it with the flag `--ignore-ancestry` and it completed successfuly. So, now I can assume that everything is fine?

Comment: Yup sorry forgot that switch checked ancestry.  I'll update my answer.